# CAS 6.2 Throws Invalid Service Ticket Exception

Tags: java, cas

In a scenario the user gets on to the login page and goes idle. After some time the user enters the credentials and CAS validates the service ticket which is success and subsequently validates the ticket again and sends the user to the error page.

I have tried to set the ST and TGT expiry time and also made sure the login page doeskin submit twice, however this behaviour is quite persistent when the users goes idle on the login page. Looking for expertise on this CAS behaviour.

CAS LOGS -

```
2021-02-17 16:56:29,564 INFO [559753f53999cd65] [org.apereo.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN\n=============================================================\nWHO: 9187ae60-0e47-11eb-aeda-12a2b8754187\nWHAT: ST-1-m4QcVAQS41fMQP1MUGelzXiUm1o-https://localhost/closing/cas for https://localhost/closing/cas/oauth2.0/callbackAuthorize?client_id=CRfgn8vNQqVFUoM7sEBL3imr&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Floc...\nACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_VALIDATE_SUCCESS\nAPPLICATION: CAS\nWHEN: Wed Feb 17 16:56:29 EST 2021\nCLIENT IP ADDRESS: ::1\nSERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1\n=============================================================\n\n>


2021-02-17 16:56:29,580 INFO [8d9699847bf6e352] [org.apereo.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN\n=============================================================\nWHO: audit:unknown\nWHAT: ST-1-m4QcVAQS41fMQP1MUGelzXiUm1o-https://localhost/closing/cas for https://localhost/closing/cas/oauth2.0/callbackAuthorize?client_id=CRfgn8vNQqVFUoM7sEBL3imr&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Floc...\nACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_VALIDATE_FAILED\nAPPLICATION: CAS\nWHEN: Wed Feb 17 16:56:29 EST 2021\nCLIENT IP ADDRESS: ::1\nSERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1\n=============================================================\n\n>
```

Comment: Please rewrite your question using the notes posted here: https://apereo.github.io/2018/09/05/effective-diagnostics/#share-pain-responsibly

Share exact cas versions (there is no version called 6.2), and share proper logs. Share the scenario, from start to finish, step by step, etc. Be precise, be exact.

Comment: Yes, without the whole scenario it is hard to help here - it is typically a protected application that calls the ST validation, not the CAS itself (see [this diagram](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.3.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol.html#web-flow-diagram)). And AFAIK, by default ST can be validated just once, it is removed thereafter - that's why you get the error on the 2nd validation...